# Apache .htaccess rewrite not working

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Hi all been banging my head against a wall on this one and looked at a lot of articles.

### My Task

I'm trying to rewrite 3 sections of a wordpress site to https if they are accessed over http:

```
/cart/ 

/my-account/ 

/checkout/
```

As well as these rewrite's worpress has added a rewrite to remove index.php out of the url.

The index.php rewrite is about the only thing that is working.

### My Config

here is my `.htaccess`

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#BEGIN MyRewrite
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (checkout|cart|my-account)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L]
#END MyRewrite

# BEGIN WordPress
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
# END WordPress
</IfModule>
```

### The Problem

Is seems I do get redirected to https but then it loops and never shows.

### Some Curl tests

In the below you can see my access the http version of /cart to be rightly told that this has moved to https /cart, So I then try the https version to be told that it has moved to the very same https version thus a loop.

```
PS C:\Users\Stephen> C:\Users\Stephen\Downloads\curl-7.23.1-win64-ssl-sspi\curl.exe -k -i http://www.mysite.com/cart
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Date: Wed, 20 Feb 2013 09:07:06 GMT
Server: Apache
Location: https://www.mysite.com/cart
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Length: 285
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>302 Found</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Found</h1>
<p>The document has moved <a href="https://www.mysite.com/cart">here</a>.</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache Server at www.mysite.com Port 80</address>
</body></html>

PS C:\Users\Stephen> C:\Users\Stephen\Downloads\curl-7.23.1-win64-ssl-sspi\curl.exe -k -i https://www.mysite.com/cart
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Date: Wed, 20 Feb 2013 09:07:06 GMT
Server: Apache
Location: https://www.mysite.com/cart
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Length: 285
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>302 Found</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Found</h1>
<p>The document has moved <a href="https://www.mysite.com/cart">here</a>.</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache Server at www.mysite.com Port 80</address>
</body></html>
```

Comment: Are you sure that your apache server has mod_rewrite installed?

Comment: @mdpc Yes because the index.php is being rewritten.

Comment: How are you testing whether it's working or not?

Comment: Perhaps editing the wrong file? (Yes, happens). Is the order of the stuff in the file right?

Comment: Turn on Rewrite logging and post the log result if you still can't find it. Exactly how you do that depends on your version of Apache.

Comment: @Ladadadada Nothing more than going to the http://www.mysite.com/mycart and seeing that it doesn't redirect. I have tried multiple browser reseting cache and another computer and it still doesn't redirect.

Comment: @JennyD I wish I could turn on logging but it's a shared host. :[

Answer (score 2):

Rewrite rules are processed in order and your first two rules (the `index.php` rules) catch every possible request.  Since they both have the `[L]` modifier, rule processing is stopped when they match, which they always do.

The redirect rules below the `index.php` rules are never even tested.  Try moving them to the top of the file (but **after** the `RewriteEngine on` line) and having the `index.php` catchall rule at the bottom.

---

As a side note, I highly recommend testing redirects with `curl` rather than using a browser.  The two specific problems this avoids are cached redirects and chained redirects (This is where URL1 redirects to URL2 which redirects to URL3 and you don't ever see URL2 in a browser.)

Either `curl -I <URL>` or `curl --include <URL>` will do the job.

Comment: Hi first of all thank you for your valuable input but before the index.php rule the url would be /index.php/cart so do i reflect that in the rule?

Comment: Do you see `/index.php/cart` in your browser?  Because if so **that** is why your redirects are not working.  A rewrite rule must match what you actually see in the browser (or what is sent in the `GET` request.)  If you see `/cart` in your browser, moving these rule to the top will work.

Comment: at the moment is see /cart I just though if I put the rule above the index.php rule then I will have an url that does not have the index.php removed yet, until it get's processed after the /cart etc rules.

Comment: Okay I moved the rules above the index.php, and now I see it redirect to https which is good but then chrome complains that there is a redirect loop. :[

Comment: Don't use Chrome.  That error message is exactly why.  Use `curl`.

Comment: I'll try curl waiting on cygwin to install... I miss my linux box.

Comment: Okay, I tried curl -i http://www.site.com/cart and I can see a 302 redirect  to the https version THANK YOU, it's 302 now as I seen to use this until I know its working. But still every browser I try either doesn't load or complains of to many redirects. Have I now created a loop of some kind?

Comment: A redirect loop is caused by a chain of redirects.  Try requesting the URL the first one sent you to.  Probably `https://example.com/cart`.  I suspect the `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off` is the problem now and the https version is redirecting to itself.

Comment: Again thanks for your help on this but doesn't the fact that the condition `https off` will only cause a redirect if were on http, If i browse direct to https https://www.mysite.com/cart I still get a redirect loop. when the only rule that should match is the index.php rule.

Comment: Okay i ran curl on the https /cart and I get a 302 for the same page and it tells me its moved to the same page.???

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: The below is wrong - it would be valid if this were in a VirtualHost context, but since it's in .htaccess, it's not.

Now that I have a little more coffee, I see that you need to include the first `/` in the RewriteRule. Like this:

```
RewriteRule ^/secure https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: In a `.htaccess` file or any Directory context (such as a `<Directory >` block), the leading slash does not exist because the directory path (`/path/to/your/directory/`) has been removed.

Comment: You're right; I missed that it's in a .htaccess.